# User access management in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I want a plugin to controll user access to each and every section of wp-a. They can post add edit or delete their own post. But they dont have any access to others post. even if they cant view there post from admin panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you mean something like that http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-access-manager/